# PyQt, SQLAlchemy - what sessions are good for?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyqt

I have this class which I use to create and manage an SQLIte database:

```
def __init__(self, db_file = None, parent = None):

    self.db = None
    self.db_connection = None
    self.db_file = str(db_file)

def db_open(self):
    self.db = create_engine('sqlite:///' + self.db_file)
    self.db_connection = self.db.connect()

def db_close(self):
    self.db_connection.close()

def db_create_voltdrop(self):
    metadata = MetaData()

    tb_cable_brands = Table('cable_brands', metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column('brand', String)
        )
    tb_cable_types = Table('cable_types', metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column('brand_id', None, ForeignKey('cable_brands.id')),
        Column('type', String),
        Column('alpha', String)
        )
    tb_cable_data = Table('cable_data', metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column('type_id', None, ForeignKey('cable_types.id')),
        Column('size', String),
        Column('resistance', Float)
        )
    metadata.create_all(self.db)
```

I instantiate this class when my MainWindow opens, use the DB and close the DB when the program quits.

I've just started learning SQLAlchemy. That code works fine. And then I came across sessions in SQLAlchemy which are also used to create and manage databases. Which way is better? What advantage do sessions have over the above way? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice for the session management is to declare it in global scope and use it.

The doc given in sqlalchemy says

`When you write your application, place the result of the sessionmaker() call at the global level. The resulting Session class, configured for your application, should then be used by the rest of the applcation as the source of new Session instances.`

So you have to create in any package level session. You can refer [this link](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/session.html#getting-a-session).

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** for your example (where `create_all` issues DDLs) it is not really important (and I am not even sure if SA supports DDL transactions), but whenever you add/delete/modify/query the objects themselves, Sessions are the way to go. See [Using the Sessions](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/session.html#id1) for more info.

**More info:**
Technically, the following statement is not correct: `... then I came across sessions in SQLAlchemy which are also *used to create and manage databases*`.
Sessions are not used to create and manage databases, but rather to provide a [UnitOfWork](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) pattern for database operations.
A simple view is to see sessions as SQL Transactions: SA Sessions to SA objects are what SQL transactions are to DML (data modification) statements. Your particular example is generating DDL statements (data definition), and many RDBMS do not even support transactions for DDLs (you cannot rollback `CREATE TABLE` statement, but should use `DROP TABLE` to cancel your work).